# How to state set initially when my page load reactjs(this.setState not woking)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have two buttons.One is Correct answer and other is User answer.
when i click on user answer, the button will show user answer data and when i click on correct button it will show correct answer data. 
But when i load the page i set `state :'user'` but in user button nothing is showing i do all thing in right way.

Here is my code

```js
export default class HotspotRemed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.user = []
        self = this
        this.buttonPrimary = 'btn-primary'
        this.typeUser=this.props.typeUser
        this.state = {
            type : 'user',
            style:'style2',
            isCorrectAns:false,
            userUpdate:[]
        }
        this.switch = this.switch.bind(this)
    }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
    if(nextProps.userXml) {
        this.setState({
            userUpdate:nextProps.userXml
        })
        this.setState({
            type:'user'
        })   
    }  
    if(window.uaXML){ 
        if(nextProps.userXml) {
            this.setState({
                userUpdate:nextProps.userXml,
                type:nextProps.typeUser
            })
        } 
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.user = this.props.userXml
    this.setState({
        userUpdate: this.user,
        type:'user'
    })
    if(window.uaXML){ 
        this.setState({
            userUpdate:this.props.userXml,
            type:this.props.typeUser
        })      
    }

}
componentDidMount() {
    if(window.uaXML){ 
        this.setState({
            userUpdate:this.props.userXml,
            type:this.props.typeUser
        })      
    }
}


    switch(type) {
        switch(type){
            case 'user' : 
            // console.log(this.user+"correct usere")
            // console.log("type3"+this.state.type)
            return (
                <div style={styleWord}>
                    <RemediationUserSpansXML userAnswers={this.state.userUpdate} correctAnswer ={this.props.correctAnswer}  xml={this.props.xml} type={this.props.type} />
                </div>
            ) 
            case 'correct' : 
            // console.log("type4"+this.state.type)            
            return (
                <div style={styleWord}>
                   <RemediationSpanXML userAnswers={this.user} correctAnswer ={this.props.correctAnswer} xml={this.props.xml} type={this.props.type} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    userButton() {
        // console.log("type5"+this.state.type)
        this.setState({
            type: this.props.typeUser,
            isCorrectAns:false
        })
    }
    correctButton(){
        // console.log("type6"+this.state.type)        
        this.setState({
            type: 'correct',
            isCorrectAns:true
        })
    }
   
    render(){
        // console.log("type7"+this.state.type)        
         return(
            <div style={wordStyle}>
                <center>
                    {/* <button type="button" class="h" id="set-review"></button>
     <button type="button" class="h" id="unset-review"></button> */}
                    <div
                        class="btn-group clearfix review"
                        id="sm_controller"
                    >
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className={this.state.isCorrectAns ? buttonStyleNormal: buttonStyleActive }
                            onClick ={this.correctButton.bind(this)}
                        >   
                            Correct Answer
                        </button>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className={this.state.isCorrectAns ?  buttonStyleActive : buttonStyleNormal }
                            onClick ={this.userButton.bind(this)}
                        >
                            Your Answer
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </center>
               {this.switch(this.state.type)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What should i do to resolve this error.
i just only want to when my page refresh it load user answer data.

Comment: what value you are passing `this.props.typeUser` to that component and what will be value of `window.uaXML`

Comment: I am passing this.props.typeUser : 'user' and window.uaXML is my xml string.

Comment: what does `console.log` says about `state.type` in `render` method and `<div style={styleWord}>` here `styleWord` is not sure if its not defined remove it.

Comment: in render this.state.type is 'user'

Comment: are you sure this code is working? You have a function named `switch` which is a reserved keyword. What is the console showing when you run it?

Comment: yes there is no issue to use reserved keyword switch. when page load first time it return blank array and after  2-3 sec those array have some value show in console. why my data is no printed on first page load